# Getting the difference between two element tree objects in Python

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I'm parsing through some xml for network device configurations. I want to find the difference in certain tag subsets.

My code is working fine, however I want to place the differences in a dictionary which will eventually be written to a log. I've iterated through the tags using ElementTree library, and now I have to either subtract one set of text from the other, or find a way to subtract two element tree objects.

Here is the code:

```
def compare_object_groups(file1_root, file2_root):
    object_group_differences = {}
    elements1 = {entry.get("name"): entry for entry in file1_root.findall(".//address-group/entry")}
    elements2 = {entry.get("name"): entry for entry in file2_root.findall(".//address-group/entry")}
    for name, group1 in elements1.items():
        group2 = elements2.get(name)
        if group2:
            if ET.tostring(group1) != ET.tostring(group2):
```

I have to subtract group2 from group1 or subtract the string representation to bring back values that aren't matching.  Is there a way to return the difference of two element tree objects?

I don't care whether or not tags are returned makes no difference.

I really would like to return the differences by using element tree objects instead of converting to string and splitting by newline, for example

elements1 - elements2

finding the differences between the two objects seems a lot cleaner than string coversion

Is there a built-in function/library/method that can achieve this for me, or any ideas?

Comment: Hmm,   any opinions?

Answer (score 0):

In case any 1 was still wondering.

I just placed item.tag from each xlm file into a seperate list and compared values for matching tags. Then updated a dictionary with differences.

```
for sub_elem1 in elem1:
        for tag in sub_elem1:
            elem1_attributes.append(tag)
    for sub_elem2 in elem2:
        for tag in sub_elem2:
            elem2_attributes.append(tag)
    for elem1 in elem1_attributes:
        for elem2 in elem2_attributes:
            if elem1.tag == elem2.tag:

       
                for member1 in elem1:
                    for member2 in elem2:
                        if member1.text != member2.text:
                            difference_attributes[file1_ip] = difference_attributes.get(file1_ip, []) + [member1.text]
                        if member2.text != member1.text:
                            difference_attributes[file2_ip] = difference_attributes.get(file2_ip, []) + [member2.text]
```